# Cannot add foreign key constraint when value is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I using `CodeIgniter` for develop my application, I have insert a constraint for this table:

**Appointments**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`book_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`start_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`end_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`notes` text,
`hash` text,
`is_unavailable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`guid_users_provider` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`guid_users_customer` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`guid_services` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_google_calendar` text,
`resources_guid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`data` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lastUpdated` varchar(36),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `guid_users_customer` (`guid_users_customer`),
KEY `guid_services` (`guid_services`),
KEY `guid_users_provider` (`guid_users_provider`),
KEY `resources_guid` (`resources_guid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Resources**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resources` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GUID` char(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`descrizione` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`sigla` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`planning` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`hex_color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`data` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lastUpdated` varchar(36),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `appointments`
ADD CONSTRAINT `appointments_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`resources_guid`) REFERENCES `resources` (`GUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The schema is builded correctly, but the problem is when I try to insert a record through my application, in particular the field `resource_guid` sometimes is `NULL`. Now, if I insert a record in `PhpMyAdmin` for test, in the `appointments` table and set the `resource_guid` as empty the record is added succesfully, but when I insert the record from my application on `CodeIgniter` I get this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`scheduler`.`appointments`, CONSTRAINT `appointments_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`resources_guid`) REFERENCES `resources` (`GUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)\",\"previous\":null,\

Now this is the content `array` of the query:

```
array(12) {
["guid_users_provider"]=>
string(36) "EE36D621-5E29-4674-81CB-B98622153E0C"
["start_datetime"]=>
string(19) "2015-12-30 23:19:00"
["end_datetime"]=>
string(19) "2015-12-31 00:45:00"
["notes"]=>
string(0) ""
["resources_guid"]=>
string(4) "null"
["is_unavailable"]=>
bool(false)
["guid_users_customer"]=>
string(36) "CDB8C010-7E51-4478-A341-F077E0460C88"
["guid_services"]=>
string(36) "31C40686-D72C-4361-B211-DCB2223552A9"
["book_datetime"]=>
string(19) "2015-12-31 01:12:39"
["hash"]=>
string(32) "5a9882faec12ab5bacb3445382176463"
["lastUpdated"]=>
string(27) "31-12-2015 10:12:39.5659760"
["GroupID"]=>
int(1)
}
```

How you can see the field `resource_guid` is NULL. Now the thing that I don't understand is (If I insert this in `PhpMyAdmin` as `resource_guid` set to `NUll`, so empty field, no error will be displayed, also from my application the error above appear).

This array is passed to the `insert` method of `CodeIgniter` like this:

```
if(!$this->db->insert('appointments', $appointment))
{
        throw new Exception("Can't add record=> " . $this->db->_error_message());
}
```

How I can insert the resource also when is NULL? I mean, in my db table structure there is no renstriction for null value, infact in the `appointments` table is set with `DEFAULT NULL`. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Appointments` Table, you have given default value as `NULL`

Instead, give `empty` value as DEFAULT.

```
resources_guid` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

To make an Existing Column as NOT NULL use `MODIFY`

```
ALTER TABLE Appointments MODIFY resources_guid char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: If I insert not null this error appear: 'resources_guid' cannot be null

Comment: Use ALTER TABLE Appointments MODIFY resources_guid INT(11) char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''

Comment: Why int(11) and later char (36) ? Anyway, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE appointments MODIFY resources_guid INT(11) char(36) NOT NULL D' at line 1

Comment: oopss..my mistake..remove the `int` , just the `char`

Comment: Now I can't add the record: Column 'resources_guid' cannot be null

Comment: Yes...since you have modified the column not to have `NULL`, it wont accept `NULL` values anymore, you have to change the code where you are inserting, instead of NULL, use ''(empty strings)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99384/discussion-between-salvatore-fucito-and-abhinav).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your input `resources_guid`

```
["resources_guid"]=> string(4) "null"
```

It's a `string` with value `"null"`, not a `boolean` `NULL`.

Pls check how you created that input. Make sure that is returning an actual `NULL` value. If you don't have control on that, you may need to change it manually by this way: (assuming the array as `$appointment`)

```
if($appointment["resources_guid"] == "null") {
     $appointment["resources_guid"]  = NULL;
 }
```

> Regarding the `FOREIGN KEY`, it should work as you have set it. There should be no problem for `NULL` values in the child field (unless the field is set as `NOT NULL`).